# C# CreatePipe() -> Protected memory error

Tags: c#, api, pipe, pinvoke, dllimport

I trying to create a pipe using C#. The code is quite simple but when the line with `CreatePipe()` call is executed I get a `System.AccessViolationException` with the following error message:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Here the COMPLETE code of my form :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CreatePipe(out SafeFileHandle hReadPipe, out SafeFileHandle hWritePipe, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpPipeAttributes, int nSize);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public DWORD nLength;
        public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
        public bool bInheritHandle;
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        sa.nLength = (DWORD)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(sa);
        sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero;
        sa.bInheritHandle = true;

        SafeFileHandle hWrite = null;
        SafeFileHandle hRead = null;

        if (CreatePipe(out hRead, out hWrite, sa, 4096))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Pipe created !");
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Error : Pipe not created !");
    }   
}
```

At the top I declare : using DWORD = System.UInt32;

Thank you very much if someone can help.

Comment: Did you try using integers instead of `SafeFileHandle` and seeing if the pointers are all valid?

Comment: Did you try using System.IO.Pipes? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.aspx

Comment: Using integers instead of SafeFileHandle lead to the same error. And I don't want to use System.IO.Pipes for severals reasons (.NET 2.0, program taken from a C++ one, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the protected memory violation is because the Windows API for CreatePipe was expecting a *pointer* value to an area of memory which the function would use as a spring board to the security attributes structure. Simply passing in the SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure would then overwrite secure memory (pages not yet allocated to your application), and hence the protected memory error.

Passing in an IntPtr to represent this *pointer*, solves your problem.

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CreatePipe(ref IntPtr hReadPipe, ref IntPtr hWritePipe, IntPtr  lpPipeAttributes, int nSize);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public DWORD nLength;
        public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public bool bInheritHandle;
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        sa.nLength = (DWORD)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(sa);
        sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero;
        sa.bInheritHandle = true;

        IntPtr attr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(sa));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(sa, attr, true);

        IntPtr hWrite = new IntPtr();
        IntPtr hRead = new IntPtr();

        if (CreatePipe(ref hRead, ref hWrite, attr, 4096))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Pipe created !");
        }
        else
        {
            int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            MessageBox.Show("Error : Pipe not created ! LastError= " + error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its my pleasure, I'm glad to help  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Just change the declaration, so that `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` is a pointer:

```
public static extern bool CreatePipe(out SafeFileHandle hReadPipe, out SafeFileHandle hWritePipe, ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpPipeAttributes, int nSize);
```

Comment: @Dimitri, that's the way it is, you can only accept one answer. However, when you get some more reputation, you'll be able to upvote multiple answers.