# When did SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES change and why?

Tags: c#, .net, process, pinvoke

I have some code that uses P/Invoke to launch a process and capture the standard output. (The story of why we did this using P/Invoke instead of `System.Diagnostics.Process` is long and convoluted; suffice it to say it's a requirement.) It's been working in production under heavy load for nearly a year, and the tests that exercise it have always passed.

This morning though I ran the tests, and they failed. I can't be certain when I last ran the tests prior to this morning (5/15/2014), but I believe it was 4/24/2014. The tests passed then, but failed this morning. I was getting the "PInvokeStackImbalance" error message, so I did some research, and eventually realized the signature of one of the structs used by the `extern` method (`CreatePipe` in this instance) was incorrect. I changed it, and the tests started passing again.

I'm happy to have found the fix, but I'm concerned about deployment. **Why did the signature of the struct change?** I haven't upgraded my OS or anything - I was running Windows 7 x64 on 4/24, and I'm still running it now. (The deployment environment is Windows Server 2012.) I've installed (and uninstalled) a few apps since then, but they've been light-weight 3rd-party tools, not Microsoft or system components. I assume a Windows Update hotfix is responsible, but I can't figure out which one.

To be clear, in my own code, all I changed was this:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public UInt32 nLength;
        public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
        public bool bInheritHandle;
    }
```

to this:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal class SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public int nLength = 12;
        public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero;
        public bool bInheritHandle;
    }
```

I need to be sure that the change I made to get the code working on my machine isn't going to break the app when I deploy to production. Does anyone know how to identify what necessitated the change and how to determine whether the production environment does or does not require it?

**EDIT:**

Here is the code that opens the pipe for the standard output:

```
    private PipeInfo CreatePipe()
    {
        PipeInfo pipeInfo = new PipeInfo();

        SafeFileHandle safeFileHandle = null;
        try
        {
            Native.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES pipeAttributes = new Native.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
            pipeAttributes.bInheritHandle = true;
            if (!Native.CreatePipe(out safeFileHandle, out pipeInfo.ChildHandle, pipeAttributes, 0) || safeFileHandle.IsInvalid || pipeInfo.ChildHandle.IsInvalid)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception();
            }

            if (!Native.DuplicateHandle(new HandleRef(this, Native.GetCurrentProcess()), safeFileHandle, new HandleRef(this, Native.GetCurrentProcess()), out pipeInfo.ParentHandle, 0, false, 2))
            {
                throw new Win32Exception();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (safeFileHandle != null && !safeFileHandle.IsInvalid)
            {
                safeFileHandle.Close();
            }
        }

        return pipeInfo;
    }
```

I can't exactly take credit for this code, I largely lifted it from the [.NET Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs#f8b2e604d6f1fe04)

Just to be clear on timeline:

- May 2013 - write the `CreatePipe` code with the first version of `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES`
- June 2013 - deploy; code has been running successfully ever since
- April 2014 - without any changes being made, code starts throwing stack imbalance error
- May 2014 - I change to the second version of `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` and the error goes away

Comment: SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES has never changed. And you really should not use that magic constant 12. Use `Marshal.SizeOf`. I guess you changed something else in your code. Consult your revision control history to find out what.

Comment: 12 is the incorrect value for x64.

Comment: Also, the changes you describe would not change whether or not you get stack imbalance. So you do need to get the facts straight.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I know nothing has changed in the code of the solution itself, which is why I suspect a hotfix changed something about the underlying dependencies of the solution. Also, the fact is, the first block of code produces a stack imbalance, but after changing only this struct/class in the way described, the error goes away. So the facts are straight, they just don't add up; hence my question. (Thanks for the reminder about not using magic constants; I'll look at using `SizeOf`.)

Comment: Can you show the code that has the stack imbalance

Comment: So, I never did find out what had happened. In the end, I told our deployment team that we needed to have [KB2958732](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2958732) and [KB2964358](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2964358) installed on the servers, and then we deployed to both QA and Production successfully. My theory is that some hotfix made it so `nLength` was no longer being set to a default value, and so I had to do it my code, which is probably better anyway.

Answer (score 1):

We encountered this problem on x64 and this post was the top result in our search. We were using the magic 12 for nLength just like your solution which we got from the C# source for process: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal class SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES {
    #if !SILVERLIGHT
        // We don't support ACL's on Silverlight nor on CoreSystem builds in our API's.  
        // But, we need P/Invokes to occasionally take these as parameters.  We can pass null.
        public int nLength = 12;
        public SafeLocalMemHandle lpSecurityDescriptor = new SafeLocalMemHandle(IntPtr.Zero, false);
        public bool bInheritHandle = false;
    #endif // !SILVERLIGHT
    }
```

It turns out CreatePipe expects a pointer, from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/namedpipeapi/nf-namedpipeapi-createpipe):

> lpPipeAttributes
>
> A pointer to a SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure that determines whether the returned handle can be inherited by child processes. If lpPipeAttributes is NULL, the handle cannot be inherited.

The solution is detailed in this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2537607/4489577). It works for both x86 and x64. Our code is below based on that stack overflow post and the process source (with using DWORD = System.UInt32; at the top).

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool CreatePipe(out SafeFileHandle hReadPipe, out SafeFileHandle hWritePipe,
        IntPtr lpPipeAttributes, int nSize);
        
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool DuplicateHandle(IntPtr hSourceProcessHandle, SafeHandle hSourceHandle,
        IntPtr hTargetProcess, out SafeFileHandle targetHandle, int dwDesiredAccess,
        bool bInheritHandle, int dwOptions);
        
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct PIPE_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public DWORD nLength;
        public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public bool bInheritHandle;
    }

    public static void CreatePipe(out SafeFileHandle parentHandle, out SafeFileHandle childHandle, bool parentInputs)
    {
        PIPE_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpPipeAttributes = new PIPE_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        lpPipeAttributes.nLength = (DWORD)Marshal.SizeOf(lpPipeAttributes);
        lpPipeAttributes.bInheritHandle = true;
        lpPipeAttributes.lpSecurityDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr attr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(lpPipeAttributes));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(lpPipeAttributes, attr, true);
        SafeFileHandle hWritePipe = null;
        try
        {
            if (parentInputs)
                CreatePipeWithSecurityAttributes(out childHandle, out hWritePipe, attr, 0);
            else
                CreatePipeWithSecurityAttributes(out hWritePipe, out childHandle, attr, 0);
            if (!DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), hWritePipe, GetCurrentProcess(), out parentHandle, 0, false, 2))
                throw new Exception();
        }
        finally
        {
            if ((hWritePipe != null) && !hWritePipe.IsInvalid)
            {
                hWritePipe.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void CreatePipeWithSecurityAttributes(out SafeFileHandle hReadPipe, out SafeFileHandle hWritePipe,
        IntPtr lpPipeAttributes, int nSize)
    {
        hReadPipe = null;
        if ((!CreatePipe(out hReadPipe, out hWritePipe, lpPipeAttributes, nSize) || hReadPipe.IsInvalid) || hWritePipe.IsInvalid)
            throw new Exception();
    }
}
```